# How can an event bubble to document but not to document.body?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I ran into some interesting behaviour related to event-bubbling. I have created a code-pen to illustrate this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGmxXr

All I am doing there is bind two event-listeners (or I guess three including the one that removes the button). One on the document and one on the document.body.

When clicking on the button, only the console.log from the document would show up.

Why? Wouldn't the event bubble to document.body first and then to document?

Or asked differently: how can an event bubble up to document but not stop by document.body?

```js
$(document).on("click", "button", () => console.log("document knows"));

$(document.body).on("click", "button", () =>
  console.log("document body knows")
);

$("button").on("click", e => $("button").remove());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: If you change the button click to be a log than it is fine..... something weird going on with the remove()

Comment: This is related to how JQuery binds these events and checks if they should still trigger the event. I have no idea exactly what the issue with it is without diving into the jquery source code again. But if you write functionally identical code in vanilla JS ( using something like event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON' inside the doc and body handler ),  both the document and the body log their knowledge, as you would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL/DR**: The event bubbles to both `body` and `document`. The button is not in DOM at that moment. But for `body`, before handler execution jQuery tries to ensure that `button` exists inside it. For `document`, id does't do such a check.

**Explanation**

I'm not sure why *it's designed* like this. It's just explanation *why it happens*.

First of all, the handlers are bound to `document` and `body` respectively, not to the button. When event bubbles to the `document`, jQuery tries to find descendants, specified by selector (`button` in our case) and executes the handler against each of them. Same for `body`. The difference is in the way *how* it checks the descendants.

When the event is bubbled to `document` and `body`, the button is already removed from DOM, but the button element still exists in memory and is accessible via `event.target`.

for both `document` and `body` jQuery searches the elements to execute the handler against:

1. adds `event.target` (**our removed button**)
2. adds all buttons found inside parent (`body` or `document`) (**founds none**)
3. filters the result (**which is just our button**) by some matchers to check if the buttons are really children of parent
4. Executes the handlers against found elements.

The difference in 3rd step.

**2 pieces of jQuery code are responsible for this:**

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/external/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L1985

```
outermostContext = context === document || context || outermost;
```

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/external/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js#L1925

```
var ret = ( !leadingRelative && ( xml || context !== outermostContext ) ) || (
                (checkContext = context).nodeType ?
                    matchContext( elem, context, xml ) :
                    matchAnyContext( elem, context, xml ) );
```

First piece sets `outermostContext` variable.

For `document`, the `outermostContext` is `true`, for `body` it's `body`.

Second piece sets variable `ret` which decides will the handler be called or not.

For `body`, `context !== outermostContext` is `false` so matcher proceeds to 'matchContext' and eventually returns `false`.

For `document`, `context !== outermostContext` is `true` so the matcher returns true without context check.

The meaning of this is that for `body` it tries to ensure that `button` exists inside it. For document - it does not.

Comment: That answer is what definitely would expect If I was the OP. +1

Comment: And that explains the often seen comment urging **not** to delegate from the document, but from the closest possible static parent.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It's interesting, is it by design or a bug. The intention isn't clear from code

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to find the lines in the code. If you can find anything on why jQuery handles it like that you would be my personal hero of the day :-)

Answer (score 4):

This has got be a jQuery event related problem. With the normal DOM API both `document` and `document.body` get notified correctly:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      console.log("document knows");
    };
});

document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      console.log("document.body knows");
    };
});

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
})
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Nice! You took it the other side and it's interesting. But that misses the *jQuery delegation* aspect, where the buttons's parents do not serve the delegated callback (As I would expect) once the button is removed... **Except** the `document`. I made a demo [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MxaReQ?editors=1111)

Comment: Added the delegation checker.

Comment: The behavior I would expect... And what jQuery does (except for document, which surprised me!) is the delegated callback not to execute if the element was removed by a previous event handler. With your plain JS, it's not the case. --- But I admit that it *may be a variant* of OP question.

Comment: what jQuery does is checks is the `event.target` a child of the element the listener is added to. For all "parents" except `document`

Answer (score 2):

Its because there are binding priorities in jQuery. 
When you click on a element this is the order javascript executes the event.

```
1. Event on document
2. Event on element
3. Event on the elements parent
4. Event on the parents parent
5. Ect.. Until you arrive to the body.
```

So what is happening is that you delete the button before you actually arrive to the body.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you use JQuery, you was making all listeners "point" to the button element.

According to documentation of jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/on/), the code:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "button", ...
```

and the code:

```
$(document).on("click", "button", ...
```

Do the same thing, they add a listener on your "button" element.

The second parameter is a selector for the element or sub elements that you want to put your listener.

> selector
>
> Type: String
>
> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

You can see this if you inspect the element with the browser and goes to event listeners

[image]

Comment: But if it adds it directly to the button - how is it possible that it also detects events on dynamically added elements? e.g. `setTimeout(() => $("<button>Click Me</button>").appendTo(document.body), 100)`

Comment: I don't know, probably jQuery look for listeners when DOM is changed and add all that match based on selector.